# Is it possible to have a UIViewController with two UITableViews, with two corresponding NSFetchedResultsControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UIViewController that has a UITableView for most of the content in the view controller, but an additional UITableView for an options drop down the user can summon.

Both UITableViews are populated from a table in Core Data. From Apple's template, they only seem to show how to do it with one Core Data entity at once, not two, and I'm curious if such a thing is possible.

Do I create two NSFetchedResultsControllers? How do I then handle all the delegate methods?

Comment: I would suggest putting the two in separate UIViewControllers and adding them as child UIViewControllers to a main UIViewController. Those if statements will get large really fast and hard to read after a while.

Comment: An options drop down? You mean like a UIPickerView or UIPopoverController ?

Comment: No, a custom one based on a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this whether you use tableView datasource or an NSFetchedResultsController.  In your delegate methods, just compare the tableView sent to the method to determine which tableView you are dealing with.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(tableView == self.table1) {
        //do table1 stuff
    } else {
        //do your other table stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But what do I do for all the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: I would have one controller for each table, so in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods you can do something similar to the answer I suggested above:  if (controller == controller1) { //do do stuff to table1 } else { do stuff to table2.